# Action Controller won't accept params for the input fields within my private params function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having difficulty with one of my attributes being queried within my scholarship table. I defined a private function to accept the following attributes for the scholarship "table"
• scholarship (the type of scholarship it is)
• name (the name of the individual award)
• value( the amount to award)
• gpa (gpa necessary to be apply)
• deadline (the last date to apply for the award)

I have the following specified for the provider controller where the provider's show page has a partial of the scholarships#new page and where the user can post the fund using a form tag with a post request:

```
<%= form_tag(scholarships_path, {:class => "form"}) do %>

     <%= label_tag("date of events") %>

     <%= datetime_local_field(:scholarship, :deadline) %>

     <%= label_tag("The Name Of The Fund") %>

     <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>

     <%= label_tag("Type of Fund") %>

     <%= text_field_tag(:scholarship) %>

     <%= label_tag("Contributable Amount") %>

     <%= text_field_tag(:value) %>

     <%= label_tag("GPA Considerations?") %>

     <h6><span style"font-style:italics">If No GPA is worth consideration, then submit  0.0 for this fund</span></h6>

     <%= number_field(:scholarship, :gpa, in: 0.0..4.0, step: 0.01) %>

     <%= submit_tag(:submission) %>

 <% end %>
```

The following is written within the providers_controller_path

```
def show
    @providers_scholarship = Scholarship.new
    @provider = current_provider
end



private
def provider_params
    params.require(:provider).permit(:industry, :title, :password, :email)
end
```

And the page with the following information is shown below:

```
 <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form form-control scholarship-maker" >
        <%= render "scholarships/new" %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'm getting a weird response telling me the "scholarship" parameter is empty whenever I fire a post request.

I know this is rather easy to debug, but I cannot find a solution to this problem for the life of me.

Comment: is `provider` a model?  or is the model `scholarship`?

Comment: can you post the console log showing this request?

Comment: The provider is a model and the scholarship is a model

Answer (score 0):

Your `provider_params` method requires a `provider` and permits various attributes for a provider. However you form will send the attributes not nested inside `provider`.

e.g it is expecting params something like

`{ "provider" => { "industry" => "foo", "title" => "bar", ... } }`

Updating your field_tags to include the `provider` should fix your problem.
e.g

`<%= text_field_tag(:name) %>`

would become

`<%= text_field_tag("[provider][name]") %>`

However you would probably be better of looking at using `form_for` with a `Provider` class.

Comment: Yes actually I had to resort to using a render partial and then use the form_for action helper instead, thank you that was actually a valid solution to my problem, sorry I don't have a better reputation to give you an upvote.